# Obstruction class in the local Euler obstruction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

When trying to learn about local Euler obstruction, I have read the following sentence in multiple sources, without any explanation:

> The obstruction to extending $r$ (a one-form) as a non-zero section from $\nu^{-1}(S_\epsilon)$ to $\nu^{-1}(B_\epsilon)$ lies in $H^{2n}(\nu^{-1}(B_\epsilon),\nu^{-1}(S_\epsilon);\mathbb{Z})$.

Here the setup is as follows: $\nu:Y\to X$ is the Nash-blowup of an algebraic variety of dimension $n$, and $S_\epsilon$ and $B_\epsilon$ are a $\epsilon$ sphere resp. ball around a point in $X$.

Now this is probably some basic interpretation of the group $H^{2n}(\nu^{-1}(B_\epsilon),\nu^{-1}(S_\epsilon);\mathbb{Z})$, but I do not see what is meant with this sentence. Can someone point me to a reference?

Edit: After some googling this is indeed a standard fact. Keyword is, as expected, obstruction theory. Then the claim is a result of the following: consider the fiber bundle $E:=\nu^{-1}(\Omega^1)\setminus \{\text{zero section}\}$. It is homotopy equivalent to an $S^{2d-1}$-bundle, and the group $\mathbb{Z}$ in the claim is to be interpreted as the $2d-1$-th homotopy group of this sphere.

Comment: What are $S_{\epsilon}$, $B_{\epsilon}$, $\nu$, and $n$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese A bit late, but I included more details.